# Calling a function with a getter as parameter doesn't retain refrence?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, recurrence

I am having an issue with my code, I am making a Binary Search Tree data structure, and when I call a function with a node's child, then assign a value to that child within the function, it doesn't update the node's child.

```
//*** Pseudo-ish Code ***

class BSTNode {

    private BSTNode lChild;
    private BSTNode rChild;
    private int key;

    public BSTNode(int key) {
        this.lChild = null;
        this.rChild = null;
        this.key = key;
    }

    //getters and setters for each field ^
}

class BST {

    private BSTNode root;

    public BST() {
        this.root = null;
    }

    public void insert(BSTNode currentNode, int value) {

        BSTNode newNode = new BSTNode(value);

        if (currentNode == null) {

            currentNode = newNode;
            if (this.root == null) {
                this.root = currentNode;
            }

        } else {

            //ignore the newNode == currentNode value statement right now

            if (newNode.getValue() < currentNode.getValue()) {
                insert(currentNode.getlChild(), value);
            } else if (newNode.getValue() > curNode.getValue()) {
                insert(curNode.getrChild(), value);
            }
        }
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

I still want to figure out the code myself, but I am curious as to why if I were to run this code with:

```
BST testBST = new BST();

testBST.insert(testBST.getRoot(), 10);
testBST.insert(testBST.getRoot(), 7);

System.out.print(testBST.getRoot()); 
System.out.print(" ");
System.out.print(testBST.getRoot().getlChild());
```

This will output `10` then a NullPointerException. I understand this is because somehow the 7 didn't get allocated as 10's lChild, but I don't know why? Is it a scope issue I am having, or is it because I call recursively with the getlChild() in my insert function that I don't have access to the actual private lChild field?

NOTE: I was using sysout to debug my code, and I noticed the recursion does work, and it does assign the 7 properly to currentNode, but then once the function is done running, it is like currentNode no longer references the lChild of the initial root node.

Comment: Where do you assign `currentNode` to either left or right ? I do not see it in you code. You need something like `if (newNode.getValue() < currentNode.getValue()  &&    newNode.getValue() > currentNode.getChild().getValue() ) {  /*assign current node to left node and return /*}`  (and the equivalent for right node)  before recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
BSTNode newNode = new BSTNode(value);
```

Each time computer is calling the recursive method `insert()` , it is creating a `new BSTNode()`. You just want to add one `new BSTNode()` each time but it is creating nodes again and again. For example, You want to add **3** and for this it has to call `insert()` **4** times. Instead of creating only **1** node it will be creating **4** nodes.

What I have done, apart of removing some errors, I have created the recursive `insertValue()` method in `BSTNode class`. So you dont have to keep track of `currentNode` every time you call this method. As, every Node will be calling its own `insertValue()` method.

```
//*** Pseudo-ish Code ***
class BSTNode 
{
    public BSTNode lChild;
    public BSTNode rChild;
    public int key;

    public BSTNode(int key) 
    {
        this.lChild = null;
        this.rChild = null;
        this.key = key;
    }

    /* Create INSERT function in BSTNode class so that you dont have to give the "CurrentNode" everytime
       you call this method, Now you just have to pass the "Key"*/
    public void insertValue(int insertValue)
    {
        if(insertValue < key)
        {
            if(lChild == null)
                lChild = new BSTNode(insertValue);
            else
                lChild.insertValue(insertValue);
        }
        else if(insertValue > key)
        {
            if(rChild == null)
                rChild = new BSTNode(insertValue);
            else
                rChild.insertValue(insertValue);
        }
        else;
    }
}

class BST 
{
    private BSTNode root;
    public BST() 
    {
        this.root = null;
    }

    // just create the root if not present else it'll call the recursive method of BSTNode class
    public void insert(int value)
    {
        if(root == null)
            root = new BSTNode(value);
        else
            root.insertValue(value);
    }

    // you didn't provide these methods so i wrote my own just to get your code runing 
    public BSTNode getRoot()
    {
        return root;
    }

    public int getRootValue()
    {
        return root.key;
    }
}

public class BSTMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        BST testBST = new BST();
        testBST.insert(10);
        testBST.insert(7);

        System.out.print(testBST.getRootValue()); 
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(testBST.getRoot().lChild.key);
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I have added some methods like `getRoot()` just to get your code working, as you haven't provided them.